# AChartEngine - Zoombutton Resolution

Tags: java, android, charts, achartengine

is it possible  to adjust the resolution of the zoom-buttons the resolution of the smartphone. I use the AChartApi 0.60 and Samsung Galaxy Nexus. The Buttons are to small.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually its depends upon your layout of the chart. If you can set margin means it may be big.